# Webpack and babel-loader - define-property error in corejs2

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs, polyfills

Hello I get the following error when compiling my js with webpack and babel-loader

*

> ERROR in ../vendor/xxx/xxx/assets/js/xxx.js Module not found: Error:
>   Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/object/define-property'
>   in xxx

*

This is the important part of my webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    plugins: [
                        ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
                            'corejs': 2,
                            'helpers': false,
                            'regenerator': false,
                            'useESModules': false,
                        }]
                    ],
                    cacheDirectory: 'node_modules/.cache/babel-loader'
                }
            }
        },

    ]
},
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
"name": "assets-webpack",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.development.js",
    "prod": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.production.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.0.0-beta.55",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "fancybox": "^2.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "jquery": "^2.0",
    "jquery-touchswipe": "^1.6.18",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "sprintf": "^0.1.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "webpack": "^4.17.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack-validator": "^3.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4"


   }
}
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Using import * in your js?